# Spring Security: Custom Filter, Redirections and positions

Tags: java, spring-security, filter

I am having requirement where users of my application could be SSO users or non SSO users. Incase of SSO users he would not be redirected I would just pass him to page he requested for. (not authenticate) and while for Non SSO users I have to redirect to login page.

Hence I thought of writing  my own custom AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.
Here I would check if users is SSO users ( I check if there is a user id from in request header) if he is not SSO user then I would redirect him to login page else he will continue to page he accessed.

Custom AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

```
public class UserTypeFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final String INTERCEPTOR_PROCESS_URL = "/index";

    public void setAuthenticationFailureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        super.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    public UserTypeFilter() {
        super(INTERCEPTOR_PROCESS_URL);
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String userId = request.getHeader("USERID");

        try {
            if (userId == null) {
                throw new PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException("EID param not found");
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, e);
        }

        /*if (userId == null) {
            System.out.println(" THROWING EXCEPTION FILTER");
            throw new PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException("EID param not found");
        }*/
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authRequest = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(userId, "123456");
        authRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
        Authentication authResult = getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);

        return authResult;
    }

    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Authentication request failed: " + failed.toString());
            logger.debug("Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication");
            // logger.debug("Delegating to authentication failure handler " +
            // failureHandler);
        }
        String defaultFailureUrl = "/login";

        request.getRequestDispatcher(defaultFailureUrl).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

My Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").anonymous().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/static/j_spring_security_logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and().csrf().and().addFilterBefore(new UserTypeFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean(name = "myAuthenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

     @Bean
     public UserTypeFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
         UserTypeFilter authFilter = new UserTypeFilter();
         authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
         SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
         handler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login");
         authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(handler);
         return authFilter;
     }
}
```

There are multiple problems/doubts that I have:

1) In case of Non SSO user i.e when userid is not present in header. Then as expected the redirection happens to login page. But is this way of redirection proper . Should I configure SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler?

3) Incase of SSO user my code where I am trying to create authenticate is throwing null pointer exception. I copied this code from an example online but i really don't know what to do there can someone help me with this?

2) I have configured my customfilter before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is this ok?

Is my approach of using customfilter right?